# Little confusion in Trignometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We have 2 formulas namely

$\sin \theta = 1 $ implies $\theta \in (4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$ ,  $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Also we have

$\sin \theta =\sin \alpha $ implies $\theta=n\pi + (-1)^n\alpha$

Now my doubt is that if i put $\alpha$=$\pi/2$, why aren't  the two formulas gives same result? And how do i know which one to apply?

Thanks

Comment: So what's left to show now is that $\{2 n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ $ \equiv \{n \pi + (-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. Just write down a few elements of each set, and it will become apparent why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the graph of sine curve. It is periodic with period $2\pi$, with $\pm1$ its maximum and minimum values. If it takes the value, say $0.75$ for some angle $\alpha$ then it would climb up reach the maximum value 1 and start descending. On the way back also it will take the value $0.75$. This returning  property is true for all but the extreme values.